# JavaScript - import/export (modules), file path

Tags: javascript, import, module, export

So I have a folder that looks like this:

*main-folder
js: folder
other: folder
---other/file.js // file inside other folder.
scripts.js // file inside js folder.

This is my code:
import { close } from "~/js/other/nav.js";

how can I import other/file.js to my main.js or as I named it scripts.js

Comment: Why not do: `if (results >= 4 && results <=10)` to save yourself from some typing?

Comment: @epascarello the logic skips 7

Comment: @Pointy && result !=7 :p

Comment: There should be an array that captures the logic, so that a single lookup guides the flow of computation.

Comment: @Pointy The first if picks up 7. So does not really matter

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking. But seems like you want to track all the numbers, not the last one? If that is the case you need to use an array and push to it or use a Set and add to it.

Comment: @Pointy You have the right idea... First roll equally to 7 or 11 wins the game. Or if firstroll equal to 2 or 3 or 12 looses game. So now if firstroll equal to 4 or 5 or 6 or 8 or 9 or 10. Then this number has to be match with the next roll (second roll).